# How do flutter components fit together?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm picking up flutter for what's supposed to be a quick bit of app work.  I must be missing something.  Can someone please explain how stateful components fit together?  If I have a webservice API that provides a data structure as JSON and I want to display parts of that in my app and I want to break the display down into components, how do the components get associated with the different bits of JSON?

At its simplest, I have a component to display a battery level:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class BatteryPainter extends CustomPainter {
  double level;

  BatteryPainter({this.level = 0.75});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.green
      ..strokeWidth = 5
      ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    Rect rect = Rect.fromCenter(
      center: Offset(size.width / 2, size.height),
      width: size.width * 0.9,
      height: 50,
    );

    RRect rr = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, const Radius.circular(5));

    canvas.drawRRect(rr, paint);

    rect = Rect.fromCenter(
      center: Offset(size.width / 2, size.height),
      width: size.width * 0.9 - 10,
      height: 40
    );

    double right = rect.left + (rect.right - rect.left) * level;
    rect = Rect.fromLTRB(rect.left, rect.top, right, rect.bottom);

    rr = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, const Radius.circular(5));

    paint
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    canvas.drawRRect(rr, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(BatteryPainter oldDelegate) => oldDelegate.level != level;
}

class Battery extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BatteryWidgetState createState() => _BatteryWidgetState();
}

class _BatteryWidgetState extends State<Battery> {
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      return CustomPaint(
        painter:BatteryPainter(),
        size:Size(constraints.maxWidth, 50)
      );
    });
  }
}
```

But now if I create one of these:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: Column(children: [
      ...,
      Battery()
    ]
  );
}
```

How do I pass updates to the battery state in so that the component gets redrawn?  If I keep a reference to the `Battery` object, that does me no good because it's the state that keeps the current battery level, not the widget, so there's no obvious way to change the level value.  If I pass a level into the `Battery()` constructor and the use that value in `createState` that doesn't really help either, since Dart is pass-by-value so changing the value in the top-level component which knows about changes to this value don't change the value in the battery level display component.

How are fine-grained components meant to be connected to a model like this?

Comment: `BatteryPainter({this.level}) : super(repaint: level);` note that `level` has to be `Listenable` - you can use `ValueNotifier` for example

Answer (score 1):

> How do I pass updates to the battery state in so that the component gets redrawn?

There is no simple answer. You pick one of the many [state management methods](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) and go with it.